# JSTL throws Exception when running JSP

Tags: jstl, tomcat7

I'm currently starting to test out JSTL as a replacement for scriptlets, and from a (german) sample page I've copied the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" version="2.0" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
        <head>
          <title>JSTL 1.1</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Iteration</h1>

            <ul>
              <c:forEach var="num" begin="1" end="10">
                <li>Nummer <c:out value="${num}"/></li>
              </c:forEach>
            </ul>

            <h1>Formatierung</h1>

            <p>
              Währung: <fmt:formatNumber value="10000" type="currency" currencyCode="EUR" />
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

My application container is Tomcat 7.0, the JSTL library is linked to the project (there's a different error message when it's not). Calling the listed JSP from the browser on my local installation throws this error message:

```
Jul 03, 2013 2:56:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/webapp01] threw exception [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test.jsp (line: 3, column: 3) Der Content von Elementen muss aus ordnungsgemäß formatierten Zeichendaten oder Markups bestehen.] with root cause
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 3; Der Content von Elementen muss aus ordnungsgemäß formatierten Zeichendaten oder Markups bestehen.
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2567)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2665)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:172)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:226)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:193)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
  at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It definitely seems to complain about the `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`, however, I will need to actually load the namespace definitions for JSTL 2.0, don't I?

Edit 1: Removing the manual (and wrongly formatted) import of the taglib results in an error message that I was trying to fix with the manual import:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 110: Namespace prefix c on forEach is not defined
error on line 2 at column 56: Namespace prefix fmt on formatNumber is not defined
```

I found somewhere that this was because the JSTL could not be found. However, I've added the `jstl-1.2.jar` to the project. Also, I read that this problem could be caused by not having the right Tomcat version. However, I'm pretty sure I'm running Tomcat 7.

Comment: I strongly recommend change your development environment locale to English. Whilst some of us (including me) understand German, English exception/error messages will yield much better Google results.

Comment: I'll see if I can change Eclipse to english. And maybe my Tomcat installation.

Comment: Just change Eclipse locale by adding `-nl=en_US` to startup VM argument. Tomcat locale is automatically taken into account if controlled/managed from inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to declare the JSTL tag library in standard JSP syntax in a JSPX document which is required to be well-formed XML (wherein each `<element>` **must** have a start and end tag).

This is not right. Read the [JSTL core tag library documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html):

> Standard Syntax:
>
> ```
>     <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
> ```
>
> XML Syntax:
>
> ```
>     <anyxmlelement xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" />
> ```

You already have the proper XML syntax there in `<jsp:root>`. Just get rid of the `<@ taglib %>` line altogether.

Note that using *scriptlets* is already not possible in JSPX (the `<jsp:scriptlet>` element not accounted). I'm wondering what you're trying to replace here.

---

**Update**: those unresolved XML namespaces during runtime indicate a problem in webapp's runtime classpath. Either the actual JSTL 1.1/1.2 impl is absent in the runtime classpath, or the JSTL 1.0 impl (which uses a different namespace) is *also* present in runtime classpath which got precedence in classloading. To verify/confirm that, look in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the exported/deployed WAR file (you can manually export a project as WAR by rightclick, *export*).

In order to install JSTL 1.2, just drop `jstl-1.2.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`. That's all. Do *not* fiddle around in project's *Build Path* property.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: You were right. I inserted the import after reading that missing this import could be the cause of the error message I've now documented in Edit 1.

Comment: Is this an IDE buildtime error or a runtime error? I.e. did you try to run the code anyway? Some IDEs pretend to be smarter than they actually are and gives false errors.

Comment: The error message in Edit 1 is from calling the JSP file in a browser.

Comment: Okay, then your classpath is likely polluted with JSTL 1.0 libraries which have a different namespace. What libraries do you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`? The `standard.jar` represents JSTL 1.0/1.1 impl. You should get rid of it when using JSTL 1.2.

Comment: None. Do I need to place them into there manually, meaning that configuring them at project level in Eclipse isn't enough?

Comment: Oh, you manually fiddled around in project's *Build Path* property without taking *Deployment Assembly* into account? Just don't do that. Undo that all. You should usually never have the need to fiddle around in *Build Path* property. Drop the JAR straight in webapp project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. That's all. Eclipse will then automatically set the build path right and so on. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've exported it to a WAR now (so far, only started directly from Eclipse), and the WAR contains the `jstl-1.2.jar` I've manually dropped there in the project directory. After that, I stopped the Tomcat that Eclipse started and started the system tomcat manually, and voila, it works.